# different size of element in numpy array and list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am using Python 3.4 32 bits on win 7.

I found that an integer in an numpy array has 4 bytes, but in a list it has 10 bytes.

```
import numpy as np 
s = 10; 
lt = [None] * s;
cnt = 0 ; 
for i in range(0, s):
    lt[cnt] = i;
    cnt += 1;
lt = [x for x in lt if x is not None];
a = np.array(lt);
print("len(a) is " + str(len(a)) + " size is " + str(sys.getsizeof(a)) \
          + " bytes " + " a.itemsize is " + str(a.itemsize) + " total size is " \
          + str(a.itemsize * len(a))  + " Bytes , len(lt) is " \
          + str(len(lt)) + " size is " + str(sys.getsizeof(lt)) + " Bytes ");  

   len(a) is 10 size is 40 bytes  a.itemsize is 4 total size is 40 Bytes , len(lt) is 10 size is 100 Bytes the fist element has 12 Bytes
```

Because in a list, each element has to keep a pointer to point to the next element ?

If I assigned a string to the list:

```
  lt[cnt] = "A";

  len(a) is 10 size is 40 bytes  a.itemsize is 4 total size is 40 Bytes , len(lt) is 10 size is 100 Bytes the fist element has 30 Bytes
```

So, in array, each element has 4 bytes and in list, it is 30 bytes.

But, if I tried:

```
    lt[cnt] = "AB";
    len(a) is 10 size is 40 bytes  a.itemsize is 8 total size is 80 Bytes , len(lt) is 10 size is 100 Bytes the fist element has 33 Bytes
```

In array, each element has 8 bytes but in list, it is 33 bytes.

if I tried :

```
  lt[cnt] = "csedvserb revrvrrw gvrgrwgervwe grujy oliulfv qdqdqafwg5u u56i78k8 awdwfw";  # 73 characters long

 len(a) is 10 size is 40 bytes  a.itemsize is 292 total size is 2920 Bytes , len(lt) is 10 size is 100 Bytes the fist element has 246 Bytes
```

In array, each element has 292 bytes (=73 * 4)  but in list, it has 246 bytes ?

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you get that `first element` size?  `sys.getsizeof(lt[0])`?

Answer (score 0):

The element size in arrays is easy - it's determined by the `dtype`, and as your code shows can be found with `.itemsize`.  4bytes is common, such as for `np.int32`, `np.float64`.  Unicode strings are also allocated 4 bytes per character - though the real unicode uses a variable number of characters.

The per element size for lists (and tuples) is trickier.  A list does not contain the elements directly, rather it contains pointers to objects which are stored elsewhere.  Your list size records the number of pointers, plus a pad.  The pad lets it grow in size (with `.append`) efficiently.  All your lists have the same size, regardless of 'first item' size.

My data:

```
In [2324]: lt=[None]*10
In [2325]: sys.getsizeof(lt)
Out[2325]: 72
In [2326]: lt=[i for i in range(10)]
In [2327]: sys.getsizeof(lt)
Out[2327]: 96
In [2328]: lt=['A' for i in range(10)]
In [2329]: sys.getsizeof(lt)
Out[2329]: 96
In [2330]: lt=['AB' for i in range(10)]
In [2331]: sys.getsizeof(lt)
Out[2331]: 96
In [2332]: lt=['ABCDEF' for i in range(10)]
In [2333]: sys.getsizeof(lt)
Out[2333]: 96
In [2334]: lt=[None for i in range(10)]
In [2335]: sys.getsizeof(lt)
Out[2335]: 96
```

and for the corresponding arrays:

```
In [2344]: lt=[None]*10; a=np.array(lt)
In [2345]: a
Out[2345]: array([None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [2346]: a.itemsize
Out[2346]: 4
In [2347]: lt=['AB' for i in range(10)]; a=np.array(lt)
In [2348]: a
Out[2348]: 
array(['AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB'], 
      dtype='<U2')
In [2349]: a.itemsize
Out[2349]: 8
```

When the list contains `None`, the array is object dtype, and the elements are all pointers (4 bytes integers).

Comment: 32-bit types are 4 bytes each, but 64-bit types (e.g., `np.float64`) are 8 bytes each.