# numpy array bigger than python list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In this question [Why NumPy instead of Python lists? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists) every one seems to agree than numpy array are a more compact structure.
I try to replicate this and I found than is only true when the list become huge. I am on python3.5 ubuntu 12.04

```
import sys
from numpy getsizeof

a = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
print(getsizeof(a))  # 96
print(getsizeof(numpy.array(a)))  # 128

a = list(range(1000))
print(getsizeof(a))  # 9112
print(getsizeof(numpy.array(a)))  # 8096
```

Could someone explain me why?

Comment: `getsizeof` only measures the buffer of pointers of the list, not all the objects pointed to.  This isn't a good tool for comparing the 2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33052942/901925

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40357378/901925

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40336100/901925

Comment: this is helpfull thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed overhead.  Both lists and numpy arrays have a fixed-size data structure that is used to manage the data in the container.  Numpy has a slightly larger structure, which the more compact value storage doesn't immediately overcome.